# Azure Data Factory - Custom Activity never complete

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm new to Azure and I am working on data factory and custom activity. I am creating a pipeline with only one custom activity (the activity actually do nothing and return immediately).

However, it seems that the custom activity is sent to batch account. I can see the Job and task created but task remains "Active" and never complete.

Is there anything I missed?

Job: Created and is belonged to desired application pool

[Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR84O.png)

Task: Not sure why but  application pool is n/a and never complete

[Job -> Task Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ2GA.png)

[Task application pool n/a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENwDH.png)

Code of the dummy activity. I'm using ADF v2 and therefore it is just a simple console program.
[Dummy activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URaJv.png)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out.

The problem is from the batch account. The node of the pool failed at start task which block the node to take job. I have changed the start task of the pool not to wait for success so that even if the start task failed the node can still take job.